# Vizualizar filtros convolucionais no tensorflow

Tags: python, imagem, redes-neurais, tensorflow, keras

Estou tentando vizualizar os filtros de uma rede neural e não estou conseguindo entender como exibir os filtros como imagens.
No momento estou usando a base CIFAR10 (imagens coloridas 32x32).

Estou usando essas bibliotecas

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, utils
```

Essa é a rede de teste

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (10, 10), activation='relu', input_shape=(X.shape[1:])))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (6, 6), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add( layers.Flatten( ) )

model.add( layers.Dense(128, activation='relu') )
model.add( layers.Dense(len(CATEGORIES) , activation='softmax') )
```

Com esse codigo eu retorno os filtros e mostro as dimensões deles

```
k=0
for layer in model.layers:

    if 'conv' in layer.name: 

        filter_, bias_= layer.get_weights()

        f_min, f_max = filter_.min(), filter_.max()
        filter_ = (filter_ - f_min) / (f_max - f_min)

        print('Filtros da {}° camada'.format(k+1))
        print('\n')
        print(filter_.shape)
        print('\n')

    k=k+1
```

**Saida**

Filtros da 1° camada

(10, 10, 3, 64)

Filtros da 3° camada

(6, 6, 64, 16)

A primeira camada eu consigo, mais as outras eu não entendi como funcionam as dimensões delas

Codigo para exibir os filtros (que so funciona na primeira camada)

```
k=0
for layer in model.layers:

    if 'conv' in layer.name: 

        fig= plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

        filter_, bias_= layer.get_weights()

        f_min, f_max = filter_.min(), filter_.max()
        filter_ = (filter_ - f_min) / (f_max - f_min)

        print('Filtros da {}° camada'.format(k+1))
        
        for i in range(filter_.shape[3]):

            p = filter_[:,:,:,i]

            ax = fig.add_subplot(8, 8, i+1)
            ax.imshow(p)

        plt.show()
    k=k+1
```

Comment: Porque você não faz um model.summary() pra ver isso ?

Comment: Porque eu gostaria de vizualizar os filtros como imagens e não apenas os parametros da camada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Keras, os filtros de uma camada convolucional tem a seguinte formatação: (kernel_size, kernel_size, channels_in, channels_out). Aqui explico um pouco o que cada dimensão do tensor representa:

1. kernel_size. Tamanho do filtro (3x3, 5x5, 7x7, etc),
2. channels_in. Número de canais do tensor de entrada da camada convolucional. Fica fácil visualizar da seguinte maneira. Supõe que a tua entrada é uma imagem em tons de cinza (portanto, 1 canal), então o teu tensor vai ser (kenel_size, kernel_size, 1, channels_out).
3. channels_out. Número de canais do tensor de saída, ou número de filtros.

Pro caso da primeira camada convolucional, é fácil de visualizar: você só precisa mostrar cada filtro como sendo uma imagem (de tamanho kernel_size x kernel_size). Um exeplo disso pode ser encontrado [nesse notebook colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KlTzQAGvm-tA0zhGW_hP3Q37LztBz2V_?usp=sharing), onde cada filtro é visualizado como uma imagem usando a função imshow da biblioteca matplotlib. Para mais camadas, ou com mais canais de cores, a análise fica um pouco mais complicada. [Esse post aqui](https://distill.pub/2020/circuits/visualizing-weights/) (em inglês) discute isso de maneira aprofundada.

Comment: Uma parte que eu não entendi porque mais canais de cores iriam complicar?